# Zimbra : Cancel an instance of a meet SOAP

Tags: zimbra

In the soap-calendar.txt, there is a function to cancel a meet

> CancelAppointment(DEFAULT-INVITE-ID,
>   COMPONENT-NUMBER)
>
> NOTE: If canceling an exception, the original instance (ie the one the
>   exception was "excepting") WILL NOT  be restored when you cancel this
>   exception.
>
> if  is set, then this cancels just the specified instance or range
>   of instances,  otherwise it cancels the entire appointment. If  is
>   not set, then id MUST refer to the default  invite for the appointment.
>
> <CancelAppointmentRequest id="ID_OF_DEFAULT_INVITE" comp="COMPONENT_NUM_DEFAULT_INVITE">
>
> [<tz ...>]
>   [<inst> [range="THISANDFUTURE|THISANDPRIOR"]> DATETTIME/>]?
>
> [ <m> [<e.../>*] 
>   [<su>{subject of> cancellation mail}] 
>   <mp>...</mp>
>   </m> ] </CancelAppointmentRequest>

I have a diary meet that occurs on 22,23,24 and 25th of february. I want to cancel only the meet of the 23th. I write the xml but I don't know what to put in the <inst tag. Actually, I put the calendar uuid in the "id" tag but it cancel all the meet (the 22,23,24 and 25th meets)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should better refer to the [Zimbra Soap-Api documentation](http://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.5.0/api-reference/index.html).

See the document about [CancelAppointmentRequest](http://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.5.0/api-reference/zimbraMail/CancelAppointment.html). I guess, you should use the "d" attribute to specifically select the instance you'd like to cancel. Additionally, you can leave out the "range" attribute to only have the instance you specified cancel. If you want to remove this instance and all further ones, you would set range to "THISANDFUTURE".